# Change a SKPhysicsBody's body shape

Tags: sprite-kit, physics, skphysicsbody

I don't want to change ANYTHING other than the body that defines the shape of a SKPhysicsBody. How do I do this?

I can't seem to find where I can change this.

Or even commentary on how to change it.

Yes, I know this has to be done carefully, so that it avoids all possible new collisions, overlaps, etc. But putting that aside, how do I change the body of an SKPhysicsBody?

Comment: How do you create that particular physics body? Or you ask in general? But, physics body can be created in many different ways. Anyhow, you will change its shape if you re-create it.

Comment: I think the goal it's to change for example from a PhysicsBody rectangle shape to physicsBody circle shape

Comment: You can't, you do not have access to the `path` property.  All you can do is create a new body and copy what is set in the old

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is there a easy/fast/light way to absolutely ensure that all the properties of the previous body are copied across?

Comment: no,  has to be manually done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually create a custom shape for a physics body using `CGMutablePath`, then pass it into the `SKPhysicsBody` constructor.

For example:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(.....))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(.....))

let customPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: path)
```

Comment: Can this be passed in, over and over, thereby changing the shape, or is a new physics body required for each new shape?

Comment: You can pass in the same path to create as many physics bodies as you want. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No. I want to change the body a physicsBody is using.

Comment: Have you tried setting the node's physics body to nil, then setting it to a newly instantiated physics body?