# How to Add a SkPhysicsBody to a Semicircle

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I haven't been able to add an SKPhysicsBody to my semicircle. How could I add one? (I have a random circle right now just to test it)

Here's the code used:

```
semiCircle.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2), clockwise: false).cgPath
semiCircle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
semiCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(300));
semiCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
semiCircle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
semiCircle.isHidden = false
semiCircle.strokeColor = SKColor.blue
semiCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.white
semiCircle.lineWidth = 20
semiCircle.name = "ball"
semiCircle.zPosition = 0
addChild(semiCircle)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532393/change-a-skphysicsbodys-body-shape?rq=1

Comment: Not working sorry

Comment: Here's the code that I tried to use: let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        
        let customPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: path)
        
            semiCircle.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2), clockwise: false).cgPath
            semiCircle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
            semiCircle.physicsBody = customPhysicsBody

Comment: And what's going wrong? Any errors? What's your expected result? How did you test it?

Comment: It isn't adding a physicsbody for me